# Custom error handeling and log

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, error-handling, class-design

As you know the basic method for handle error is try ... catch ... finally structure.

If we want to handle every error and save it into a file, we have to add one line to catch section for save error details.

The question is:
Is there any solution for override catch event?

In other words, consider try ... catch ... finally structure similar to other application events and override catch section, run our custom code next run catch section code.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of best ways of implementing these kind of problems is by using aspect-oriented programming.

In fact, you want something that must:

- Handle exceptions.
- Log exceptions.

There's a concept called IL weaving that's based on post-compilation code injection which eases aspect-oriented programming.

That's you can do something before and after executing methods and properties and, at the end of the day, this is "handling any exception thrown in any assembly member", isn't it?

For example, I've some experience with PostSharp, which implements IL weaving and makes it incredibly easy to work with it: it's attribute-based.

You need to implement a custom attribute deriving some PostSharp base one, and it can override some method that will be invoked before and other after executing the method/property where you place your atrribute.

Exception handling could be implemented as a "HandleExceptionAttribute" and logging "LogAttribute" (it's just an example!).

Learn more about PostSharp on (if I'm not wrong, it has a free community edition):

- http://www.sharpcrafters.com/

And some "how-to":

- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/09/first-steps-with-post-sharp.aspx

Comment: It's wonderful. I read your solution and see that links. But i really did not understand what this can do! Is it can handle any error in all project classes even if programmer write her/his catch section?

Comment: That's it! You can do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch specific Exception types

```
Try
{do something}
catch (SystemException ex) { }
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) { }
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Is this what you mean?

Otherwise you can implement an [Exception Handler Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599787.aspx)

Comment: No my dear. Thank you for your answer. I want to override catch section that occur even if we write catch (Exception ex) { ... } code